# variation of parameters leads to improper integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$2y''+12y'+18y=cos(t)=f(t)$$

$$r = -3, r = -3$$

$$y_g(t)=c_1e^{-3t} + c_2e^{-3t}t$$

$$y_1(t)=e^{-3t}$$
$$y'_1(t)=-3e^{-3t}$$
$$y_2(t)=e^{-3t}t$$
$$y'_2(t)=e^{-3t} - 3e^{-3t}t$$

$$W[y_1,y_2] = e^{-3t}(-3t+1)e^{-3t} - (-3e^{-3t})te^{-3t} = e^{-6t}$$

using variation of parameters I get

$$v_1(t) = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{(-cos(t))(te^{-3t})}{e^{-6t}}$$

$$v_1(t) = \frac{-1}{2}\int cos(t)te^{3t}dt$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go to use the identity

$$\cos t  = \frac{e^{it} +e^{-it}} {2}$$

then integration by parts.